# Weblogic datasource monitoring statistics report

Tags: weblogic, datasource, monitoring

I want to get the report for statistics for datasource monitoring from weblogic console.

Scenario is, I do not have access to production weblogic console and the issue is for pool limit exceed.

I want to monitor connection count (statistics) for at least a week and decide the limit for this if any way to get report for this statistics will be great.

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find this information in : [Monitoring WebLogic JDBC Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13737/monitor.htm). You want to use the Connection Usage Profile = `PROFILE_TYPE_CONN_USAGE_STR`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is useful to get statistics.